# Footnote in LaTeX master document

Tags: formatting

How can create a footnote in the LaTeX master document which will appear on all pages of the pdf output?

Comment: That is not really a foot note. You probably need to add this to the footers or add it as a globally positioned element on all pages. Cannot do much else without more information about your document.

Comment: use package `fancyhdr` and define a footer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please give a sense of the scope of the footer material: A few words that fit on a single line, or a multiple-line paragraph, or something inbetween?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you are looking for is to set a footer. Here is an example of how to do this using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{This is my personal footer that will appear in every page of the document.}

\begin{document}

This is my document.

\end{document}
```

`\fancyhf{}` clears the previous definition of header and footer.

`\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` makes the default header line invisible.

Finally, in the example the footer is aligned to the center `[C]`, but other alignments are possible.